# Correct way to set margins

Tags: margins, best-practices

I set the margins of my document in this way using the `geometry` package

```
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
```

Is it a correct way or does there exist a better way?

Comment: This is correct as long as it gives the result you want.

Comment: yeah it seems it gives me the expected results...

Comment: Given that you are using the same amount of left and right margins (and also for top and bottom) you can also write: `\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}`

Comment: @egreg I think he is more asking which are his limits. If you want to write an article, of course you can set the margins all of 0.5cm, because apparently *it gives the result you want* (shows what you write). But may be you should be limited because it looks bad. For me, without being any professional, I usually use 3cm for hmargin and 4cm for vmargin. But perhaps, this is not *the good choice*.

Comment: @Manuel, these things depends on your font size etc. (and what you are writing). In a single column text one normally wants ~66 characters per line (~45 for two columns), see e.g. [Notes on Book Design](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memdesign). It is hard to say something about the margins without saying something about the text.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with egreg; if you get the result you want then everything is fine. But let me mention that some document-classes have their own way of setting the margins. Personally I swear to memoir (when I have the choice), which is one of the above mentioned document-classes. Here you can set the margins using

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}  % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout
```

And I believe that this way is preferable with `memoir`.

Comment: could you update this to be in the form of a minimal working example please

Comment: The commands:       \setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}  % Upper and lower margin only work with the Memoir package. The text box won't let me indent code, I don't know why.

Comment: @user26732 this answer already states that these commands are for use with the `memoir` document class. Displayed code is not supported in comments, you must instead use inline code (delimited with backticks `\``).

Comment: I didn't see the section in the user's manual about backticks.