# Change font size through \documentclass

Tags: margins, fontsize

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Inductive step-\\
Assume the statement holds for $n \in \left\{ 1, 2, ... n\right\}$

\end{document}
```

Changing the 12pt in documentclass to something bigger doesn't change the size. Any idea what's wrong?

[image: Output pdf]

Am I the only one who thinks that the default font size is too small and the margins are too big?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The standard classes only provide 3 options for font size by default, with `12pt` being the largest. `extarticle` offers extended font sizes or you can use one of the other classes. You might find that you prefer something like `memoir` or one of the Koma-Script classes if you want a different default for page margins etc., too.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84774/correct-way-to-set-margins

Comment: 12pt is the standard size. There is also 11pt and 10pt. You can change these by using `\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont` and use the geometry package to adjust the margins.

Comment: You can also use the KOMA Script classes and have more choices for the base text fontsize.